# Looking inside XML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need to get the text that is in between this bit of XML Code using Javascript

```
<description>&lt;b&gt; Logic Devices&lt;/b&gt;&lt;p&gt;
FLEX 10K&lt;p&gt;
FLEX 6000&lt;p&gt;
Based on the following sources:
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt; Databook, January 1998
&lt;li&gt;CD-ROM Gigital-Library, December 1998
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;author&gt;Created by librarian@cadsoft.de&lt;/author&gt;
</description>
```

And I guess as a bonus, how would I turn all those < and ul> along with all the other possible combinations into the readable text they represent.  Is there like an alphabet look-up deal I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var xml = '<description>&lt;b&gt; Logic Devices&lt;/b&gt;&lt;p&gt;FLEX 10K&lt;p&gt;FLEX 6000&lt;p&gt;Based on the following sources:&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt; Databook, January 1998&lt;li&gt;CD-ROM Gigital-Library, December 1998&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;author&gt;Created by librarian@cadsoft.de&lt;/author&gt;</description>'

var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

console.log($xml.find('description').text())
```